# Django search for static parts of the site

Tags: django, search, full-text-search, django-haystack

I am planning to use Django-Haystack to add a search component to my site. This will take care of the data I have in my models.py. I however also want data which is not in a model, but part of templates to be searchable. How can I get this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a django app called haystack-static-pages that should help here. It's not been updated for a while so I doubt it will work with haystack 2.0, but I hope this might be of some help to you:

https://github.com/trapeze/haystack-static-pages